# Discord.js bot is there a way to check mention?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

[Attached below is a part of my code. What it does is that if I type "pain.throw @user" it will throw out an embed and some text. However, if I don't mention a user, my code doesn't work. Is there a way someone can show me to let the bot spit out a message and say "You have to mention someone for this to work" or something. Thank you. Any help is appreciated.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDY43.png)

Comment: Please do not provide images of code.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a

```js
if (!usernamegedUser) return message.channel.send("Try again, except mention someone");
```

Under the

```
const usernamegedUser = message.mentions.users.first();
```